# Marmalade SDK, what should I use?

Tags: cross-platform, cocos2d-x, box2d, marmalade

I'm using the Marmalade SDK, my question is, can I use only cocos2d-x and Box2d, and not use Iw2d, IwGx, IwGL altogether (or vice versa)?

And what factors will my choice depend on regarding if I want to use cocos2d-x and Box2d, and not all the others (or vice versa)?

P.S I'm developing a 2d game that will need minimal physics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Cocos2d-x without using Iw2D, IwGX, etc. Cocos2d should abstract these things for you. Cocos2D-x is a complete game engine, where Iw2d is only a rendering system that renders 2d sprites für you.

What systems you want to use depend on how much low-level work you want to do yourself.

If you use Cocos2D-X it will have support for a lot of features out of the box. Like scenes, sprite-rendering, skeleton-animation, effects, particles etc..

Iw2D just abstracts the low level OpenGL-API so that you can render sprites with just one function call. But it does not support animations and other features. So you would have to include other projects or write the functionality yourself.

IwGx is a wrapper for OpenGL which introduces states so that the OpenGL-API is easier to handle.

IwGl is just plain OpenGL and you would have to implement even the rendering yourself.

Which one to use depends on the project. When you just want to make a 2d game cocos-2d or Iw2D should give you enough control to succeed doing so and also you will save time because you can use already tested systems.

Box2d is only used to drive the physics simulation of your game world. You can use it with all of these systems.

Depending on your C++ and game programming experience i suggest to first use a game engine (like cocos2d-x) or Iw2D to learn the basics. For your second game you can still switch to a more low level api if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can focus on the `Quick` flavor of Marmalade, which has cocos2d and box2d bundled up with Lua. That will make for easy start and development.

Comment: I want to use C++ for experience so Quick is not an option.